# how to append view into dialog box by using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I got my view in the success event of ajax but I don't know how to append this view into a dialog box .

here, is my code.

```
<script>
    $("#id4").click(
        function() {
            alert("Clicked");
            debugger;
            var model = $(this).attr('PID');
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                type: "Get",
                url: "/Projects/GetProjectDetails",
                data: {
                    "projectId": model
                },

                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#div2").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        height: 400,
                        width: 600,
                        appendTo: data
                    });

                }

            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

i m new in asp.net mvc and jquery.

Comment: `$("#div2").html(data);`?do you really need `async : false?`

Comment: Can you show us the value of `data`?

Comment: If it is `html` element show us that element.

Comment: i m getting my  partial view on data .